# Googlesheet Appscript getSpreadsheetbyname() runs extremely slow

Tags: performance, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a simple appscript that fetches the first row from a data sheet and populate it into another sheet in the same worksheet. It is usually executed within 1-3 secs.

From last few days I am observing that the script take a long time at getSheetByName() for the first sheet. Once the first sheet is executed the next sheet does not take time. The below logs shows it took more than 90 secs just to execute getSheetByName()  for the first sheet (Calling Dashboard). The second sheet is executed almost instantaneously with the rest of the script. This is happening randomly after several executions and it is affecting our work.

I have tried SpreadsheetApp.flush(); but that does not help when this happens.

I am wondering if there a better way of handling this or I have missed anything? I have gone through several online resources but could not find any guidance on this kind of issue.

I am attaching my script and any help will be very much appreciated!!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0sd8.png) (Logs snapshot attached)

```
function fetchNextCallBack() {

Logger.log("Start Function")
const myGooglSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
Logger.log("Active Spreadsheet initiated")

//SpreadsheetApp.flush();
const shUserForm = myGooglSheet.getSheetByName("Calling Dashboard");
Logger.log("Calling Dashboard Initiated")

const datasheet = myGooglSheet.getSheetByName("Call Backs");
Logger.log("Call Backs Initiated")

shUserForm.getRange("C8:C22").clearContent();
shUserForm.getRange("F10:F18").clearContent();
shUserForm.getRange("M4:M6").clearContent();

Logger.log("Dashboard cleared")

const values = datasheet.getRange("A3:N3").getValues();
Logger.log("Call back Data fetched")

shUserForm.getRange("C8").setValue(values[0][5]); // vehicle no
shUserForm.getRange("C10").setValue(values[0][3]); // mobile no
shUserForm.getRange("C12").setValue(values[0][2]); // customer name
shUserForm.getRange("F12").setValue(values[0][4]); // model
shUserForm.getRange("C14").setValue(values[0][1]); // call type
shUserForm.getRange("F14").setValue(values[0][6]); // service type
shUserForm.getRange("F20").setValue(values[0][13]); // cre
shUserForm.getRange("C18").setValue(values[0][11]); // appt date
shUserForm.getRange("F18").setValue(values[0][12]); // appt slot
shUserForm.getRange("F10").setValue("REMINDER CALL");

Logger.log("Call back Data populated in dashboard")
}
```

the script is expected to be completed within 1-3 secs. However it takes sometime more than 90 secs abruptly. It always get stuck in the following line:

```
getSheetByName()
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please don't add logs as image, instead add them as text.

Answer (score 0):

The code you show seems fine. Chances are that the *spreadsheet* is on the heavy side, and that makes accessing the data slow. You can confirm whether that is the case by making a copy of the spreadsheet and deleting everything on every tab, leaving say 25 blank rows on each tab. Then test the code in the blank spreadsheet and see if the same thing happens.

To improve spreadsheet performance, see [these optimization tips](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/102271339).

Comment: thanks for the feedback.. I will try with the suggestions and update here