# Significant lag time in Apps script formSubmission trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have a Google Sheet with an embedded piece of Apps Script code. This has an installable form submission trigger inside of it. There are two forms in the Google Sheet, so the code for the trigger determines which form was submitted, and then takes appropriate action. However, I have recently been having this trigger fail around 20% of the time. Even when it succeeds, it takes around 5 minutes to run -- and this is fairly simple code. It grabs values from a few small ranges in the Google Sheet, collects attachments from the form submission if applicable, and then sends an email according to some rules.

However, when it fails, this happens after 5-6 minutes, and I either get this error:

```
Exception: Service Spreadsheets timed out while accessing document with id xxxxxxxx.
    at formSubmission(Form Submission:58:75)
```

Or this one, after around 90 seconds:

```
Exception: Document xxxxxxx is missing (perhaps it was deleted, or you don't have read access?)
    at formSubmission(Form Submission:50:18)
```

In both cases, the spreadsheet ID is the sheet that the script is embedded in--so it definitely has access to that file. And of course, 80% of the time, it runs without error.

Here is line 50:

```
let sht = sSht.getSheetByName("Key Status Form");
```

And for context, I previously have:

```
let sSht;
...
sSht = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
```

And here is line 58:

```
keyCompletionEmails = constantsSheet.getRange(keyCompletionEmailsStart).getDataRegion().getValues().flat();
```

For context:

```
let constantsSheetNm = "User Inputs";
let constantsSheet = sSht.getSheetByName(constantsSheetNm);

let keyCompletionEmailsStart = "J1";
```

A few additional pieces of information about the spreadsheet:

- My forms have upwards of 4k responses each
- I have half a dozen additional tabs in the spreadsheet that have colors, conditional formatting, complex vlookups, and around 500 rows with 30 columns

I'm really stumped on why this is happening. Is this a form response volume issue? I've never had this problem with Apps Script before and have had forms with many thousands more of responses. I tried deleting and re-installing all triggers, but no luck. I'd welcome any thoughts or troubleshooting steps I could take.

I've been asked to provide some more of the code. I have several global variable declarations, and then here's the main part of my code before it hits those two errors:

```
function formSubmission(e) {
  let vals = e.namedValues;
  sSht = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // Prevent invoicing form from running the email script
  if (vals["QUESTION NAME"] == undefined) {
    console.log("Wrong form");
    // Update number formatting for plain text before all the email attempts in case of error
    let sht = sSht.getSheetByName("SHEET NAME");
    let lastRow = sSht.getLastRow();
    sht.getRange(lastRow - 2, 2, 3).setNumberFormat("@STRING@");
    return;
  }

  let var1 = vals["qu 1"][0];
  let var2 = vals["qu 2"][0];
  let var3 = vals["qu 3"][0];
  let var4 = vals["qu 4"][0];
  let imageUrl = vals["Please consider uploading a photo"][0];
  console.log(imageUrl);

  // Update number formatting for plain text before all the email attempts in case of error
  let sht = sSht.getSheetByName("SHEET NAME");
  let lastRow = sSht.getLastRow();
  sht.getRange(lastRow - 2, 2, 3).setNumberFormat("@STRING@");


  constantsSheet = sSht.getSheetByName(constantsSheetNm);
  
  keyCompletionEmails = constantsSheet.getRange(keyCompletionEmailsStart).getDataRegion().getValues().flat();
```

As a bit of additional context, when they don't fail, line 50 takes around 115 seconds to run, and line 58 takes around 125 seconds. (I timed this using `console.time()`.)

Comment: Providing more samples of the code, and perhaps, the entire code would greatly help identify what is causing the issue. And yes, it is somehow related to the form response volume but we can't entirely say if it is the root cause unless it's possible for you to provide us with more information.

Comment: I've added lots of more specific code to this question; is there anything else I should add to get it re-opened?

Comment: `let sht = sSht.getSheetByName("SHEET NAME");` Is there actually a sheet named "SHEET NAME"? `let lastRow = sSht.getLastRow();` this line should be failing. `getLastRow()` is NOT a valid method for `Spreadsheet` - it works with `Range` & `Sheet` - given the preceeding line of code, my guess is that this line should read `let lastRow = sht.getLastRow();`

Comment: Line 58 (`keyCompletionEmails`) combines several commands - which should not be a problem. But `getDataRegion()` expects a "dimension" value [doc ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdataregiondimension) but there is none. What is returned for `Logger.log(constantsSheet.getRange(keyCompletionEmailsStart).getDataRegion().getA1Notation())`

Comment: Debugging#1: I am inclined to think that the volume of form responses is not an issue and that the errors that you are experiencing don't seem to be directly related to Event Objects of other aspects of the form responses. The first issue to check is whether there is a delay in the execution of the trigger; the `Executions` tab will show the time that the event was triggered, and the Response timestamp will show the time of submission.

Comment: DEBUGGING#2: if there is delay in the trigger, then create a test script and compare the time to run lines 50 and 58 alone. If the times are similar to the triggered script then read Googlesheet Appscript getSpreadsheetbyname() runs extremely slow [duplicate][ref](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74740113/1330560)